# Convert Integer to String in JSON, Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input JSON :

```json
{
  "a": "value1",
  "b": [
    {
      "X": 1234
    },
    {
      "X": 4567
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the integer values to be converted to a string. Basically add double quotes to the integer.
Desired output is:

```json
{
  "a": "value1",
  "b": [
    {
      "X": "1234" // want to add double quotes
    },
    {
      "X": "4567" // want to add double quotes
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec with **toString** function embedded such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "b": {
        "*": {
          "X": "=toString"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Could you share a link for learning jolt transformations.

Comment: you're welcome @prathikvijaykumar , I've learnt through studying on the samples from [this jolt demo site](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com) .